# Angular signal computed(() => toSignal()) throws Error

Tags: angular, angular-signals

Following code

```
  source$ = of(1);
  value = computed(() => toSignal(this.source$));

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.value());
    });
  }
```

Throws
ERROR
Error: NG0602: toSignal() cannot be called from within a reactive context. Invoking `toSignal` causes new subscriptions every time. Consider moving `toSignal` outside of the reactive context and read the signal value where needed. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0602

Why do I get this error?
I know that I could just use the toSignal without computed then it works. However I want to make use of the computed-memoization.

When splitting it up in two steps it does not throw:

```
  source$ = of(1);
  v =  toSignal(this.source$);

  value = computed(() => this.v());

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.value());
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computed()` is not supposed to create new signals (inside the computation function), it should [derive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) (in other words, "compute") the new value from values of one or multiple signals.

> I know that I could just use the toSignal without computed then it works. However I want to make use of the computed-memoization.

Regular signals also use memoization - they will not notify consumers if the new value is equal to the existing one ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/primitives/signals/src/signal.ts#L76)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great explanation. Especially that you pointed out that regular signals are also memoized! :)